SQLalchemy Bulk insertion from cursor object
i'm stuck with a problem thats been bothering me for a while , I wanted to insert into a table as bulk insert but the resultant object I have is a cursor object which I obtained from following,
sql_select = text("SELECT * FROM LANDING_ZONE.BATCHES").execution_options(yield_per=1000)
result = session.execute(sql_select)

The result object is cursor object , I can read the rows one by one but like this
            for row in result:
                print(row)

But I want perform bulk insert , How is this possible having the insertion as follows:
            sql_insert = text("INSERT INTO EBS_LANDING_ZONE.GL_JE_BATCHES_COPY (ID, NAME, FULLNAME) VALUES (:val1, :val2, :val3)")

Maybe different depending upon the answer,
I am referring to cx_oracle bulk insert method.
The code is as follows
start_time_for_read_and_write = time.time()

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

try:
    with session as session:
        session.begin()
        
        try:
            # Execute raw SQL to select data
            sql_select = text("SELECT * FROM 
                              LANDING_ZONE.BATCHES").execution_options(yield_per=1000)
            #with profiled():
            result = session.execute(sql_select)
            #logger.debug("Start Query: %s", result)
            
            # Iterate through the results if needed
            for row in result:
                print(row)
        
            # Execute raw SQL to insert data
            sql_insert = text("INSERT INTO LANDING_ZONE.BATCHES_COPY (ID, NAME, FULLNAME) VALUES 
                             (:val1, :val2, :val3)")
#           session.execute(sql_insert, row)
#           session.execute(sql_insert, {"val1": 1, "val2": "John", "val3": "Doe"})  
            #logger.debug("Start Query: %s", sql_insert)

            print(" Statement for Insertion Executed successfully till now !!! ")

        
        except Exception as e:
            session.rollback()
            print("\n --------- \n Transaction rolled back due to error:", e)
            raise
            
       except Exception as e:
            print("\n --------- \n Transaction rolled back due to error:", e)


If you are fetching and inserting into the same DB, then don't fetch to Python. Instead use an INSERT SELECT so the data doesn't have to be transferred across the network from the DB to Python (and back).  Are you using SQLAlchemy 2?  See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/whatsnew_20.html#change-6047 for the performance improvements for bulk inserts.  This will also let you use the latest cx_Oracle version, which was renamed to python-oracledb.
